Find cells with a garbled mix of letters and numbers
Thanks for your help. I have a Google Sheet of usernames and would like to highlight/filter out the spam submissions, which are almost always of a format like:

zIdTfnMxdEOpM OR lXsIeqXWSKgIaS OR jqmwjlkjwy

Just a random string of characters. Is there a formula or some kind of data validation that I can use to identify such submissions? The list is about 10,000 usernames long.
I have not tried approaching this problem yet.
